# Convert a Node in an XML from European to US Decimal Formating

Tags: xslt

I Need to convert a Decimal Node which is in European format to US formating. Please help me.
The XML Looks like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Order>
  <Header>
    <OrderNumber>PO000001</OrderNumber>
    <OrderDate>20150108</OrderDate>
    <BuyerCode>00132</BuyerCode>
    <SupplierCode>V00048</SupplierCode>
    <ShipTo>
      <shipCode>00132</shipCode>
      <address1>Askent Sok. No:3/A Kat:1 </address1>
      <address2>Kosifler İş Merkezi</address2>
      <shipCity>İÇERENKÖY/ATAŞEHİR/İSTANBUL</shipCity>
      <shipPostCode>TR-34752</shipPostCode>
      <shipCountry>
        <shipCountryCode />
        <shipCountryName />
      </shipCountry>
    </ShipTo>
    <OrderText>
      <TextHeader />
    </OrderText>
    <Lines>
      <LineNumber>10000</LineNumber>
      <ItemNumber>AICM00320-WU9E1</ItemNumber>
      <Quantity>1,1</Quantity>
      <Uom>PC</Uom>
      <DeliveryDate>20150122</DeliveryDate>
      <LineText>
        <TextLines />
      </LineText>
    </Lines>
    <Lines>
      <LineNumber>20000</LineNumber>
      <ItemNumber>AICM00400-WU9E1</ItemNumber>
      <Quantity>5.000</Quantity>
      <Uom>PC</Uom>
      <DeliveryDate>20150122</DeliveryDate>
      <LineText>
        <TextLines />
      </LineText>
    </Lines>
    <Lines>
      <LineNumber>30000</LineNumber>
      <ItemNumber>AICM00400-WU9E1</ItemNumber>
      <Quantity>10</Quantity>
      <Uom>PC</Uom>
      <DeliveryDate>20150122</DeliveryDate>
      <LineText>
        <TextLines />
      </LineText>
    </Lines>
  </Header>
</Order>
```

I need to format only the Quantity Node, which is repeated through out the XML.
I have used an xslt to convert all the decimal node from the US to European format. It look like below

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:decimal-format name="eu" decimal-separator=',' grouping-separator='.' />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[number()=number()]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(., '#.##0,##########', 'eu')" />
    </xsl:copy> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I need a similar XSLT which convert all the Quantity Node (only quantity node). Please help me guys. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<xsl:template match="*[number()=number()]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(., '#.##0,##########', 'eu')" />
    </xsl:copy> 
</xsl:template>
```

with

```
<xsl:template match="Quantity">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(translate(., ',.', '.'), '#,##0.##########')" />
    </xsl:copy> 
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Do you really need the 'us' <xsl:decimal-format>? It only  re-declares the defaults, doesn't it?

Comment: You are right, I kind of mechanically transformed the existing code, making the changes necessary to implement the change, as the format required is the default it suffices to use `format-number` without a third argument. I will edit to make that change.